# How to add the year to a trim in a dynamic table

Tags: excel-formula

[image: Excel]

Hi, I wanna concatenate in the result of my formula into the last cell in the rigth "Trim.2" the year of the trim found in the dynamic table. The formula is a vlookup of the lowest "Rentabilidad" (Revenue). So I need the result as "Trim.2 2016" not only the trim.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it is not a very elegant solution, the following should work:

```
=LET(
    values,$F$4:$F$13,
    items,$E$4:$E$13,
    min,MIN(values),
    match,MATCH(min,values,0),
    items_reordered,INDEX(OFFSET(items,0,0,match),SEQUENCE(match,1,match,-1)),
    item,INDEX(items,match),
    year,INDEX(items_reordered,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(items_reordered),0)),
    item&" "&year
)
```

which gives the result as shown here:

[image: Example_Screenshot]

You will only have to adjust the cell references for the variables 'values' and 'items' within the `LET()` function